# Understanding of spirit grammar

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

While going through the documentation I read that

for a string of doubles separated by a comma we could go like this (which I understand)

`double_ >> * (',' >> double_)` or `double_ %`

but what does the following expression mean. Its supposed to split comma separated strings into a vector and it works. I would appreciate it if someone could kindly clarify it. I am confused with `-` operator I believe its a difference operator but I cant figure out its role here

`*(qi::char_ - ',') % ','`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*(char_ - ',')` means "match zero or more characters but ','", and it can also be written like this: `*~char_(",")`. On the other hand, `*char_` means just "match zero or more characters".

To understand, why the exclusion is needed, just try with and without it:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp>
int main()
{
    using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
    std::vector<std::string> out1, out2;
    std::string s = "str1, str2, str3";
    bool b = parse(s.begin(), s.end(), *~char_(",") % ",", out1); // out1: ["str1", "str2", "str3"]
    b = parse(s.begin(), s.end(), *char_ % ",", out2); // out2: ["str1, str2, str3"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`qi::char_ - ','` matches all characters but `,` to prevent the inner expression from being too greedy.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read [EBNF](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-14977.pdf) standard to understand Boost.Spirit.